# How to convert the following date format in salesforce

Tags: apex

I have my date in following format:
**2014-01-20 00:00:00**
I want it in the following format 
       **1/20/2014(mm/dd/yyyy)**
But i want it as date variable not as a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have a date 'as a date', not as a string. The format you are talking about (2014-01-20 00:00:00) is just a visual representation of a value contained in variable of a DateTime type. If you want the date to appear in the specified format (1/20/2014), just output it using [**format()**](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Datetime_format_2.htm) method:

```
Datetime yourDate = Datetime.now();
String dateOutput = yourDate.format('dd/MM/yyyy');
```

Comment: @BarCotter tnx for the edit

Comment: Date.format(string format) - seems to no longer be supported. It looks like there is only a default format() with no parameters that returns a value based on the user locale - http://sforce.co/1DbYQ5O